# Apache CXF:The message has expired

Tags: web-services, apache, cxf, soapui, jboss-eap-6

Environment :

1. Apache CXF 2.7.8
2. Jboss EAP 6
3. SoapUI for testing client Side

I tried to implement for simple authentication i.e with password simple text type, it is working but when i tried to implement for password digest type ,then giving me exception:

> unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: The message has
>   expired org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The message has
>   expired

**I am giving new nonce value for each request and time within five min diff**

WSS4JInInterceptor Bean class defination:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" /> 
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" /> 

    <jaxws:endpoint id="orderProcess" implementor="demo.order.OrderProcessImpl" address="/OrderProcess" >

      <jaxws:inInterceptors>
         <bean
            class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                  <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken"/>
                  <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordDigest"/>
                  <entry key="passwordCallbackRef" value-ref="myPasswordCallback"/>
               </map> 
            </constructor-arg>
         </bean>
      </jaxws:inInterceptors>
      </jaxws:endpoint>
      <bean id="myPasswordCallback" class="service.ServerPasswordCallback" />  
</beans>
```

Client xml request Code:

```
  <soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ord="http://order.demo/" 
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
 <soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security>
           <wsse:UsernameToken>
                                <wsse:Username>joe</wsse:Username>
                                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">PE7F51/oyWFVMsiZURuUwjoZVPY=</wsse:Password>
                         <!--<wsu:Created>2013-12-17T13:12:00.429Z</wsu:Created>-->
                           <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">efPSkfHXTM6NFDDD1CJHsw==</wsse:Nonce>
                              <wsu:Created>2013-12-23T12:17:15Z</wsu:Created>
               </wsse:UsernameToken>


</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ord:processOrder>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <customerID>234</customerID>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <itemID>0908923</itemID>
            <price>23423</price>
            <qty>1000</qty>
         </arg0>
      </ord:processOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When i tried to call the service i am getting exception as

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">ns1:MessageExpired</faultcode>
         <faultstring>The message has expired</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can any one tell me where i am making mistake?

Comment: server and client are on same machine. Checked the server timezone also.. they are correct. Also I am giving new nonce value for each request and time within five min diff

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a bug in earlier version of wss4j. If you are parsing the date using SimpleDateFormat, you might want to set the time zone to UTC (Zulu time).

```
sdf.setTimeZone("UTC");
```

This however has been fixed in 2.0-beta.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-ws-security-dom/2.0-beta/org/apache/wss4j/dom/message/token/UsernameToken.java#226

Edit: This is not a bug in wss4j. The specification states that the time zone must be in UTC.